# Facebook ActionScript 3 API not working in FlashDevelop

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api, flashdevelop

I am writing a little test program, and I have a problem regarding the ActionScript 3 Facebook API (Graph_API_Web_1_8_1.swc).

I am using FlashDevelop, and I correctly added the [SWC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_SWC_file) file to the "lib" folder.

I also imported the Facebook API correctly in my class file (the auto-finish function of FD recognizes all code from there).

BUT, once I start compiling my code, I get the following error:

> Error: Access of undefined property Facebook

for each line of code, that includes a Facebook call (such as `Facebook.init(...)`, `Facebook.login(...)` and `Facebook.logout(...)`).

I added a screenshot of my FlashDevelop setup to clarify things:

[image]

This is even more mysterious to me, since the [AIR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Integrated_Runtime) application with the FacebookDesktop API is running without any errors.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Which version of Flex SDK do you use for compilation? Which player version do you target?

Comment: Flex SDK 4.6.0 and i'm targeting Flash Player 10.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has happened to me several times. Don't waste your time looking into which ActionScript 3 SDK SWC version or Flex SDK you are using. It's just a weird bug. Instead, do the following.

1. Close FlashDevelop
2. Create a completely new project
3. Add the Facebook SWC to library

Then it should work. If not, reboot. It happened to me several times. I hope this helps.